# How to show last value in views in rails and mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I am working on Rails app which has Mongodb. My model contain a portfolio class which has an array field named folders.I am doing this in app console

```
@portfolio=Portfolio.last
```

I get this return:
  #"Folder 1", "stocks"=>[{"name"=>"Atul auto", "id"=>"stock id1", "qty"=>"10"}]}, {"name"=>nil, "stocks"=>[{"name"=>"Caner fill", "id"=>"stock id2", "qty"=>"15"}]}]>

But when I use this in my controller and use the instance variable in views i am getting this return :
Portfolio:0x007ff97802cff0 
 The number keeps changing every-time i refresh the page. If i use this 
 `@portfolio=Portfolio.all.to_a` 
I get same return in views as of console. Any guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute

```
@portfolio = Portfolio.last
```

@portfolio is a Portfolio object (which you can verify in the console by calling @portfolio.class).  You can get the address of that object by calling @portfolio.to_s, which will match the output you are getting, which suggests that you are implicitly calling to_s on your @portfolio object in the view.

If, instead, you call @portfolio.inspect, you will get output similar to what you showed first.  @portfolio.inspect returns a String.  Thus, you could use @portfolio.inspect in the view to produce an output similar to what you are trying to produce.

If you call Portfolio.all, you get a Mongoid selector.  Portfolio.all.to_a will use that selector to load all of the entries from the Portfolio MongoDB collection into an array.  Portfolio.all.to_a.to_s will produce a similar output, but with quotes escaped.  Thus, in views, the implicit .to_s call on to_a is producing the similar output in the view as in the console.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly output an Object of a type. , If you do you will get the address of the object. You need to do something like this in your view:

```
<%= @portfolio.stocks.name %>
```

Comment: The final answer would be as my field is folders.@portfolio.folders.